# Shell script to subtract 1 sec from date type

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have script to generate two dates in the format `YYY-MM-DD` `HH:MM:SS` from the given date(`YYYY-MM-DD`):c

```
#!/bin/bash
test=$(TZ=America/New_York date -d "$1 00:00:00")
date_diff=1
startDate=$(date --date="${test} -${date_diff} day" "+%Y-%m-%d %T")
echo $startDate
date_diff=0
enddate=$(date --date="${test} -${date_diff} day" "+%Y-%m-%d %T")
echo $enddate
```

Now I need to subtract `n` seconds from `$enddate`. I tried converting time to a long number and do subtraction and convert back to original format. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Converting to long, subtracting, and converting back *is* the easy way.  Although it would probably be easier if you just generate the dates as epoch times in the first place so you don't need to do the initial conversion.  Dates and time formats in general should always be stored as longs and only converted to human readable forms when being presented to humans.

Comment: @WilliamPursell is right. It seems unlikely that you need to **generate** 2 dates in that format. Maybe you need to at some point **display** the generated dates in that format. Just generate the dates as seconds since the epoch, do whatever math you have to do on them as such whenever you need to do that, and display them as YmdT whenever you need to do that too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I have clear what you mean with `date_diff` for `startDate`...
Anyway `date` can grab and give dates in epoch format, so it should be easy for you to add or subtract some seconds.

Just for a poc, try something like that:

```
date=$(date +%s) ### now
offset=300 #five minutes in seconds
newdate=$((date + offset)) ### added 300 seconds
date=$(date --date="@$newdate" "+%Y-%m-%d %T") ### got the new date in whatever format I chose.
```